# cakephp can't update table with set

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, set, save

I have a problem with updating database table in cakephp... 
So I have a profile page where the logged in user can see and update his personal information. Here is my solution for it (yes I know it's not the best...)

```
if($this->request->is('post')) {
    $data = $this->request->data['user-profile'];
    // $uid = $this->Session->read("WebUser.id");
    $uid = 1;
    $user_data = $this->WebUser->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$uid)));             
    $updated_fields = '';
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        if($key != 'state'){
            if(empty($value)) {                                                             
                $this->Session->setFlash("Please fill in all the required fields");
                return;
            }
        }               
        if($user_data['WebUser'][$key] != $value) {
            if($key == 'email') {
                $mail_check = $this->WebUser->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('email'=>$value, 'id !='=>$uid)));
                if($mail_check) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash("This e-mail is already registered");
                    return;
                }
            }
            $updated_fields .= "'".$key."'=>'".$value."',";
        }               
    }
    if($updated_fields != '') {
        $updated_fields .= "'modified'=>'".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'";
        $this->WebUser->read(null, $uid);
        $this->WebUser->set(array('first_name'=>'John','modified'=>'2014-12-30 10:53:00'));
        if($this->WebUser->save()) {
            $this->printr($this->data);
            $this->WebUser->save();
            $this->Session->setFlash("Success : Profile data is now modified", array("class"=>"success_msg"));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash("Error : Data modifying isn't complete. Please try again!");
        }
    }
    return;
 }
```

So this code fetches the user info from the database and looks for those fields which are edited on profile page. Problem is when I want to save the data it give me back false and didn't save it... Does someone have a solution for this?

Comment: Is there any error message printed when user submit this form?

Also, could you please attach your View code. I think is edit.ctp or something...

Answer (score 0):

Try putting 
$this->WebUser->validationErrors;
in else part and check whether there are any validation errors or not.

Like this:

```
if($this->WebUser->save()) {
                $this->printr($this->data);
                $this->WebUser->save();
                $this->Session->setFlash("Success : Profile data is now modified", array("class"=>"success_msg"));
            } else {
                echo "<pre>";print_r($this->WebUser->validationErrors);die();
                $this->Session->setFlash("Error : Data modifying isn't complete. Please try agin!");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to set `id` [directly](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array)?

```
$this->WebUser->id = $uid;
```

Also, CakePHP is automatically update [`modified`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#using-created-and-modified) field in your table after any transactions. So you don't have to set it directly (but you can if you want any other date value).

About validation. I recommend you to read about **[Data Validation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html)** in CakePHP, because that validation is not good, it's can be handled by models.

Also. You can get any validation errors from models using `Model::$validationErrors`.

```
debug($this->Recipe->validationErrors);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code was that didn't wanted to save the posted data ( debug($this->WebUser->save) has give me back false). At the end I didn't found the solution why this code not worked but the conclusion is that you never need to use more users table than one. So now I have a Users and Groups tables, and different type of users are connected to their groups(Admin, User, ...).